# bootstrap dropdown menu close on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dropdown menu (bootsrap) with accordion invested in it. I want when I am click on accordion or other item in menu, dropdown menu should not be closed. I am write for this some code

```
 $('.dropdown-menu').bind('click', function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
```

dropdownmenu was work to do, (not close when you click) but accordion stopped working

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/5210/ resposive <768

Comment: Could you please share a better snap of the code ? Or upload it at http://jsfiddle.net..